# DRF Cursor Pagination example

Tags: pagination, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to setup [CursorPagination with DRF](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#cursorpagination) for a list of transaction records (ordered by creation date).
I can't figure out how to do an initial request because I don't know the cursor yet at that stage. Surprisingly, I can't find an example of this.

Also, is there a way to set the page size per request with CursorPagination, the PageNumberPagination have **page_size_query_param** and **max_page_size** and they aren't there for CursorPagination.

Here's what I have so far:

```
class RecordPagination(pagination.CursorPagination):
    page_size = 10

class RecordsOverview(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = RecordSerializer
    logging_methods = ['GET']

    queryset = Record.objects.all()
    pagination_class = RecordPagination

    # Note: this is my way to dynamically set the page size, 
    # it is totally hacky, so I'm open to suggestions 
    # is_number method is left out for brevity
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        page_size = request.GET.get('page_size', '')

        if self.is_number(page_size) and int(page_size) > 0:
            self.paginator.page_size = int(page_size)

        return self.list(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Then in my test I do a GET request:

```
response = self.client.get(GET_RECORDS_URL, data={'page_size': 2})
```

I get back a 'next' url that looks something like this:

```
http://testserver/api/v1/records/?cursor=cj0xJnA9MjAxNy0wOS0yMCsxNCUzQTM0JTNBNDkuNjUxMDU4JTJCMDAlM0EwMA%3D%3D&page_size=2
```

If I do **get(next_url)** I will get the next records OK, and this time I don't have to pass **data={'page_size': 2}**.

Please, let me know if I can do all of this in a cleaner and more consistent way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is how I use CursorPagination without any complications:

```
from rest_framework.pagination import CursorPagination

class CursorSetPagination(CursorPagination):
    page_size = 5
    page_size_query_param = 'page_size'
    ordering = '-timestamp' # '-created' is default

class MyListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = MyObject.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MySerializer
    pagination_class = CursorSetPagination
```

Comment: '-created' is default, not '-creation'

Comment: @TotoBriacNo, it's `ordering = '-created'`